# Epoxy resin and wood movement

Tags: technique, finishing, finish-selection, wood-movement

I am considering putting an epoxy resin finish on a table top for a nice thick and smooth finish (it will cover the side edges as well).

Will there still be wood movement after the epoxy has cured?

What will happen if there is wood movement?

Will it bow the table top or split the epoxy?

The wood is red cedar and it is only finished on the top side. However, I am considering putting a couple coats of lacquer on the underside to help seal the wood completely. The tabletop is approximately 42" x 84" x 1.25". This is the epoxy resin kit I am considering using.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will there still be wood movement after the epoxy has cured?

Yes, some at least (assuming the underside is not sealed).

> What will happen if there is wood movement?

It depends on many factors, the major one being the wood — not just species but the individual pieces, their MC and stability. A lot of movement could cause cracks in the finish for sure.

> Will it bow the table top or split the epoxy?

Obviously there's no way to directly answer that except to say: it might. It has happened therefore it can/might happen to yours. But obviously many other users haven't experienced problems.

> I am considering putting a couple coats of lacquer on the underside to help seal the wood completely.

Highly desirable from what I've read.